# Question about sums of complex convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I know that:

> $$\log(1+z)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^{n},\quad\forall z\in D(0,1)$$

And I have to prove that $\forall \theta\in$ [-$\pi$,$\pi$]:

> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\cos(n\theta)=\log\left(2 \cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$
>   $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin(n\theta)=\frac{\theta}{2}$$

I would be grateful if someone could help me to obtain these sums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $$z=e^{i\theta}=\cos (\theta )+i\sin(\theta ) \implies z^n = e^{in\theta}=\cos (n\theta )+i\sin(n\theta )$$

then

$$\log(1+z)=\log(1+e^{i\theta})=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}z^{n}=$$

$$=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\cos (n\theta )+i\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\sin (n\theta )$$

and

$$\log(1+z)=\log(1+e^{i\theta})=\log(e^{\frac{i\theta}2}+e^{-\frac{i\theta}2})+\log(e^{\frac{i\theta}2})=\log\left(2\cos\frac{\theta}2\right)+i\frac{\theta}2$$

then compare the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: Could you assure that $log(zw)=log(z)+log(w)$? I think that It is correct just if $z$ and $w$ are in the first quadrant and that is not our situation...

Comment: @user719004 To check that we can consider the exponential form for $1+e^{i\theta}=re^{i\alpha}$ with $r=\sqrt{(1+\cos \theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}=\sqrt{2+2\cos \theta}=2 \cos \frac{\theta}2$. Then the real part is fine. For the imaginary part we can proceed in a similar way and of we need to take the principal value for the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Just simply substitute $z=\cos \theta$ and use $$\cos \theta =2\cos^2{\theta\over 2}-1$$